# error: ‘::acos’ has not been declared using ::acos;

Tags: gcc, clion, math.h

I encountered this error while trying to build a cpp project using CLion. Here is the error message:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/cmath:102:11: error: ‘::acos’ has not been declared
   using ::acos;
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/cmath:121:11: error: ‘::asin’ has not been declared
   using ::asin;
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/cmath:140:11: error: ‘::atan’ has not been declared
   using ::atan;
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/cmath:159:11: error: ‘::atan2’ has not been declared
   using ::atan2;
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/cmath:180:11: error: ‘::ceil’ has not been declared
   using ::ceil;
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/cmath:199:11: error: ‘::cos’ has not been declared
   using ::cos;

...
```

In the project, there is a custom header file called `~/someproject/src/math.h`. Changing the `~/someproject/src/math.h` file name to a non-conflicting name such as `math1.h` (and updating its references accordingly) resolves the error.

Does anybody know of another solution to this that does not require a name change?

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions:

- Use relative includes e.g. `#include "../src/math.h`
- Use a patch component e.g. `#include <src/math.h>`
- Fix your include path which seems to contain something like `-I/usr/include`, so that the standard include directories are included before your custom directories.

Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html